# EMR Disable node label

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm newly trying out EMR. By default, the EMR AMI 5.28.0 seems to label the nodes (CORE, DEFAULT) and the yarn application master seems to run in CORE label.
How to reconfigure it so that the application master can be run on either CORE or TASK node.

Note : I've googled and tried multiple option like updating yarn.node-labels.enabled to false in yarn-site.xml, but none seem to work.

Comment: The application master should only run on the master node, not the CORE or TASK. what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jordanm: Thanks for the response. I believe you got it confused with Resource Manager. I definitely don't want my application masters to run in master node.

FYI : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html

Comment: BTW, I'm planning to use the node for purely computing (having S3 as storage layer). Scaling in CORE node will be slow compared to TASK node due to additional HDFS Service. So, I'd like to scale TASK node and I'd want my application masters to be running in one of the TASK node.

Note : I'm planning to use this as persistent cluster for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EMR release version 5.19.0 and later uses the built-in YARN node labels feature to launch application master on CORE nodes only.

Because Spot Instances are often used to run task nodes, Amazon EMR has default functionality for scheduling YARN jobs so that running jobs don’t fail when task nodes running on Spot Instances are terminated.

I don't recommend launching AM on any node's type. Instead, you would consider using on-demand core nodes and spot for task nodes.

Beginning with Amazon EMR 6.x release series, the YARN node labels feature is disabled by default. The application master processes can run on both core and task nodes by default. You can disable the YARN node labels feature by configuring following properties:

> yarn.node-labels.enabled: false

For information about specific properties and how to disable it, see [Amazon EMR Settings To Prevent Job Failure Because of Task Node Spot Instance Termination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html#emr-plan-spot-YARN).

**References**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html

Answer (score 0):

Run this script from MASTER NODE

```sh
sudo sed -i.bak  "/yarn.node-labels.enabled/d" /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml
sudo sed -i "/yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression/d" /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml

sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager
```

If you are planning to incorporate with bootstrap-action make sure you sure running this only on master.